# How do I change the polygon fill color and border color for SpatialPolygons objects?

Tags: polygon, r

I have SpatialPolygons or SpatialPolygonsDataFrames which I'd like to plot.  How do I change the color using the three plotting systems in R (base graphics, lattice graphics, and ggplot2)?

Example data:

```
library(sp)
Srs1 = Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))), "s1")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))), "s2")

SpDF <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame( SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2)), 
            data.frame( z=1:2, row.names=c("s1","s2") ) )
spplot(SpDF, zcol="z")
```

[image: test map]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Base graphics (`plot`)**

For base graphics, `col=` sets the fill and `border=` sets the border color.

```
plot(SpDF, col="red",border="green")
```

If you want a choropleth map, set `col=` to a vector of colors, one for each polygon's data value.

[image: base graphics]

**Lattice graphics (`spplot`)**

Unlike base graphics, the `col=` option for lattice graphics controls the border color.  For no border, [set `col=NA` or `col="transparent"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12682751/636656).

```
spplot(SpDF, zcol="z", col=NA)
```

[image: no border]

For the polygon fill, set `col.regions` to a standard R color scheme (`gray`, `rainbow.colors`, `topo.colors`, etc.):

```
spplot(SpDF, zcol="z", col.regions=gray(seq(0,1,.01)))
```

[image: col.regions]

**ggplot2**

As usual for ggplot2, you specify the levels and it picks the color scheme.  You can override the scheme for the whole plot, however.  Details to follow at some point.

Comment: Great question/answer. Perhaps you would like to add information about setting the background colour. To set the background colour in `spplot`, use `par.settings = list(panel.background=list(col="lightblue"))`.